# php pdo code to append no with date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**column name**

coupon

coupondate

startingdate

I am generating coupondate based on coupon and startingdate.

**FOR EX -**

if coupon  =   500,501 and startingdate = 24-02-2015

then coupondate generates like below..

coupondate = 23-03-2015,23-04-2015

**But I need to append coupon with coupondate**

**FOR EX -**

500 - 23-03-2015

501 - 23-04-2015 like wise..

plz help to get above output

below is my code

```
$coupon = $_POST['coupon'];                         
                    $startingdate = $_POST['startingdate'];                         
                    $coupons = explode(',', $coupon);                       
                    $dates = Array();
                    for ($no = 1; $no < count($coupons) + 1; $no++) 
                    {
                    $dates[] = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $no . " MONTHS -1 DAYS"));                        
                    }                       
                    $coupondate = implode(',', $dates);
```

Comment: can you add the values of $_POST['coupon']

Comment: yes this is also inserting in database but in seprate column....

Comment: I need to append the $_POST['coupon'] – with every $dates

Comment: You need a output of $coupondate as 500 - 23-03-2015, 501 - 23-04-2015,..

Comment: exactly i want this output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the foreach instead of for loop and append the coupon code along with the date.

```
$coupon = $_POST['coupon'];
$startingdate = $_POST['startingdate'];
$coupons = explode(',', $coupon);
$dates = Array();
$no = 1;
foreach($coupons as $coupon) {
    $dates[] = $coupon . " - " . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($startingdate . " +" . $no . " MONTHS -1 DAYS"));
    $no++;
}
$coupondate = implode(',', $dates);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($coupondate); //out put you required
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir...its working but after some change in your code.....i change $coupons = $_POST['coupon']; to this  $coupon = $_POST['coupon'];