# php code to count values in column and add this value in date

Tags: php, pdo

coupon = 700,701,702,703

startdate  = 25-02-2015

For example - Now there are 4 values present inside coupon column.

**what I Need**

When I search 700 , then it selects startdate and add +1 months to startdate because 700 is in 1st position and it generates output like below

for ex- 25-03-2015

When I search 701 then it get startdate and +2 months in startdate because 701 is in 2nd position and it generates output like below

for ex- 25-04-2015

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM receipt_entry WHERE coupon  = :coupon'); 
        $result->execute(array(':coupon' => "$q"));    
        $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $info = array();
        foreach($data as $row) {                        
            $startingdate = $row['startingdate'];   
$coupon = $row['coupon'];       
            $generateddate = $row['coupondate'];            
            $cWeb = $row['customer_name'];
            $receipt = $row['receipt_no'];
            $book = $row['book_no'];
            $booking = $row['bookingdate']; 
                  $info[] = array('web' => $cWeb,'rec' =>$receipt,'book' =>$book,'booking' =>$booking,'date' =>$generateddate );
        }
        echo json_encode($info);    
    }
?>
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691613/php-pdo-code-to-append-no-with-date/28692119#28692119

Comment: is `coupon a string or array` ???

Comment: coupon is a varchar column

Comment: as @KarthikN said, he has already given the answer, please refer the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must customize to your solution, see this example:

```
$coupon = '700,701,702,703';
$startdate = '25-02-2015'; 
$startdate = date_create("25-02-2015");

$find = '702';

$array_coupon = explode(',', $coupon);
$add = array_search($find, $array_coupon) + 1;

date_add($startdate, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$add Months"));
echo date_format($startdate, 'd-m-Y');
```

EDIT: In your code should be like this:

```
<?php
        if(!empty($_GET['q'])) {
           $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=circulation_scheme_prepaid', 'root', '');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $q = $_GET['q'];
            $result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM receipt_entry WHERE coupon  = :coupon'); 
            $result->execute(array(':coupon' => "$q"));    
            $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $info = array();
            foreach($data as $row) {                        
            $startingdate = $row['startingdate'];   
            $coupon = $row['coupon'];       
            $generateddate = $row['coupondate'];            
            $cWeb = $row['customer_name'];
            $receipt = $row['receipt_no'];
            $book = $row['book_no'];
            $booking = $row['bookingdate']; 

            $startdate = date_create($startingdate);
            $find = $_GET['q'];

            $array_coupon = explode(',', $coupon);
            $add = array_search($find, $array_coupon) + 1;

            date_add($startdate, date_interval_create_from_date_string("$add Months"));
            echo date_format($startdate, 'd-m-Y');

                  $info[] = array('web' => $cWeb,'rec' =>$receipt,'book' =>$book,'booking' =>$booking,'date' =>$generateddate );
            }
            echo json_encode($info);    
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: what columns are coupon and strartdate? And how you obtain 700 or 702?

Comment: you obtain startdate with $row['startingdate'];  ? and coupon?

Comment: and 702 is $_GET['q']?

Comment: I edit the answer, see and don't forget check as correct

Comment: sir your code is working exactly as i want....thanks for this but the problem is when i enter 700 it does not get any thing and when i enter 700,701,702,703 then it populate all dates it get all dates exactly as i want.....

Comment: i need to explode my input suppose as i enter 700 then it get  25-03-2015...just it...

Comment: but till i am accepting your solution you are great..thanks a lot...but plz do correction in code as i suggest...